# Bloomberg VBA - BLPSubscribe method returning "#N/A Sec" for CUSIP input

Tags: vba, bloomberg

I am attempting to pull down the SECURITY_DES field value for a known CUSIP of unknown Fixed Income type (could be a corporate, treasury, mortgage- or asset-backed, etc.).  I am using a declared variant to return the Bloomberg response, which has been showing "#N/A Sec" no matter how I structure my request.

I am running this within Excel and have the "Bloomberg Data Type Library" Reference added.  I will paste the code below; I have tried formatting the CUSIP as /CUSIP/xxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxx CUSIP, IDxxxxxxxxx, all without luck.  I tried Googling for formatting assistance but was having trouble finding matching discussions which worked out for me.

```
        Dim BloombergModule As BlpData
        Set BloombergModule = New BlpData
        Dim BloombergReturnData As Variant
        Dim BloombergFields(0) As String
        ' Prepare request for the SECURITY_DES field, "Security Description"...
        BloombergFields(0) = "SECURITY_DES"
        BloombergReturnData = BloombergModule.BLPSubscribe([CUSIP], BloombergFields)
```

I placed a breakpoint just after the last line pasted above; when I watch the BloombergReturnData variable, I see "#N/A Sec" in the BloombergReturnData(0,0) expression, which is what I expect -- only with the security's actual description returned instead of "#N/A Sec".

If you haven't caught on yet, I'm not a programmer by trade but have been using Bloomberg and VBA lately to fill some gaps around the office.  Based on what I've read, I suspect that I have to pass in the fixed income type (Corp, Govt, Mtge, etc.) however I don't know that within my current data set and would have to track that down somehow.

Using Bloomberg's GUI, I can type in "IDxxxxxxxxx" (x's representing a CUSIP) to arrive at the main menu for a security.

Here are a few sample CUSIPs:
428236BR3,
500255AV6,
912828UE8,
49126PET3,
912828SC5,
912828MS6,
02225AFW7

**How do I format my BLPSubscribe request to return the Security Description from Bloomberg successfully?**

---

---

EDIT: This has been answered.  I was using an old reference and structure which Bloomberg no longer supports.  Using information from a blog post written by Mikael Katajamäki, I restructured my call using the updated reference ("Bloomberg API COM 3.5 Type Library") and the security name format "/cusip/xxxxxxxxx".  The updated code is below (keep in mind that you will need the class module from Mikael Katajamäki's blog post if you intend on copy this structure):

```
        ' BCOM_wrapper is from Mikael Katajamäki's Bloomberg Class Module
        Dim BloombergModule As BCOM_wrapper
        Set BloombergModule = New BCOM_wrapper
        Dim BloombergReturnData As Variant
        Dim BloombergFields(0) As Variant
        Dim BloombergSecurities(0) As Variant
        Dim SecurityDescription As String
        ' Prepare request for the SECURITY_DES field, "Security Description"...
        BloombergFields(0) = "SECURITY_DES"
        BloombergSecurities(0) = ("/cusip/" & CStr(SQLResults![CUSIP]))
        ' getData() is from Mikael Katajamäki's Bloomberg Class Module
        BloombergReturnData = BloombergModule.getData(REFERENCE_DATA, BloombergSecurities, BloombergFields)

        ' I used an absolute reference to the (0,0) slot since the nature of my use here is always just a single security
        SecurityDescription = BloombergReturnData(0, 0)

        Range("D" & CStr(Right(Target.Address, 2))).Value = SecurityDescription
```

Mikael Katajamäki's Blog Post: http://mikejuniperhill.blogspot.com/2013/06/bloomberg-v3com-api-wrapper-update-for.html

Archive of Mikael Katajamäki's class module (please notify me if this is against the rules and I will delete):

```
Option Explicit
'
' public enumerator for request type
Public Enum ENUM_REQUEST_TYPE
    REFERENCE_DATA = 1
    HISTORICAL_DATA = 2
    BULK_REFERENCE_DATA = 3
End Enum
'
' constants
Private Const CONST_SERVICE_TYPE As String = "//blp/refdata"
Private Const CONST_REQUEST_TYPE_REFERENCE As String = "ReferenceDataRequest"
Private Const CONST_REQUEST_TYPE_BULK_REFERENCE As String = "ReferenceDataRequest"
Private Const CONST_REQUEST_TYPE_HISTORICAL As String = "HistoricalDataRequest"
'
' private data structures
Private bInputSecurityArray() As Variant
Private bInputFieldArray() As Variant
Private bOutputArray() As Variant
'
' BCOM objects
Private bSession As blpapicomLib2.Session
Private bService As blpapicomLib2.Service
Private bRequest As blpapicomLib2.REQUEST
Private bSecurityArray As blpapicomLib2.Element
Private bFieldArray As blpapicomLib2.Element
Private bEvent As blpapicomLib2.Event
Private bIterator As blpapicomLib2.MessageIterator
Private bIteratorData As blpapicomLib2.Message
Private bSecurities As blpapicomLib2.Element
Private bSecurity As blpapicomLib2.Element
Private bSecurityName As blpapicomLib2.Element
Private bSecurityField As blpapicomLib2.Element
Private bFieldValue As blpapicomLib2.Element
Private bSequenceNumber As blpapicomLib2.Element
Private bFields As blpapicomLib2.Element
Private bField As blpapicomLib2.Element
Private bDataPoint As blpapicomLib2.Element
'
' class non-object data members
Private bRequestType As ENUM_REQUEST_TYPE
Private bNumberOfDataPoints As Long
Private bCalendarType As String
Private bFrequency As String
Private bMaxDataPoints As Long
Private bStartDate As String
Private bEndDate As String
Private nSecurities As Long
Private nSecurity As Long
'
Public Function getData(ByVal requestType As ENUM_REQUEST_TYPE, _
ByRef securities() As Variant, ByRef fields() As Variant, _
Optional ByVal calendarType As String, Optional ByVal dataFrequency As String, _
Optional ByVal startDate As Date, Optional ByVal endDate As Date) As Variant()
    '
    bRequestType = requestType
    bInputSecurityArray = securities
    bInputFieldArray = fields
    '
    If (bRequestType = ENUM_REQUEST_TYPE.HISTORICAL_DATA) Then
        '
        bCalendarType = calendarType
        bFrequency = dataFrequency
        '
        If ((startDate = CDate(0)) Or (endDate = CDate(0))) Then _
            Err.Raise vbObjectError, "Bloomberg API", "Input parameters missing for historical data query"
        bStartDate = convertDateToBloombergString(startDate)
        bEndDate = convertDateToBloombergString(endDate)
    End If
    '
    openSession
    sendRequest
    catchServerEvent
    releaseObjects
    getData = bOutputArray
End Function
'
Private Function openSession()
    '
    Set bSession = New blpapicomLib2.Session
    bSession.Start
    bSession.OpenService CONST_SERVICE_TYPE
    Set bService = bSession.GetService(CONST_SERVICE_TYPE)
End Function
'
Private Function sendRequest()
    '
    Select Case bRequestType
        Case ENUM_REQUEST_TYPE.HISTORICAL_DATA
            ReDim bOutputArray(0 To UBound(bInputSecurityArray, 1), 0 To 0)
            Set bRequest = bService.CreateRequest(CONST_REQUEST_TYPE_HISTORICAL)
            bRequest.Set "periodicityAdjustment", bCalendarType
            bRequest.Set "periodicitySelection", bFrequency
            bRequest.Set "startDate", bStartDate
            bRequest.Set "endDate", bEndDate
            '
        Case ENUM_REQUEST_TYPE.REFERENCE_DATA
            Dim nSecurities As Long: nSecurities = UBound(bInputSecurityArray)
            Dim nFields As Long: nFields = UBound(bInputFieldArray)
            ReDim bOutputArray(0 To nSecurities, 0 To nFields)
            '
            Set bRequest = bService.CreateRequest(CONST_REQUEST_TYPE_REFERENCE)
            '
        Case ENUM_REQUEST_TYPE.BULK_REFERENCE_DATA
            ReDim bOutputArray(0 To UBound(bInputSecurityArray, 1), 0 To 0)
            Set bRequest = bService.CreateRequest(CONST_REQUEST_TYPE_BULK_REFERENCE)
            '
    End Select
    '
    Set bSecurityArray = bRequest.GetElement("securities")
    Set bFieldArray = bRequest.GetElement("fields")
    appendRequestItems
    bSession.sendRequest bRequest
End Function
'
Private Function appendRequestItems()
    '
    Dim nSecurities As Long: nSecurities = UBound(bInputSecurityArray)
    Dim nFields As Long: nFields = UBound(bInputFieldArray)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim nItems As Integer: nItems = getMax(nSecurities, nFields)
    For i = 0 To nItems
        If (i <= nSecurities) Then bSecurityArray.AppendValue CStr(bInputSecurityArray(i))
        If (i <= nFields) Then bFieldArray.AppendValue CStr(bInputFieldArray(i))
    Next i
End Function
'
Private Function catchServerEvent()
    '
    Dim bExit As Boolean
    Do While (bExit = False)
        Set bEvent = bSession.NextEvent
        If (bEvent.EventType = PARTIAL_RESPONSE Or bEvent.EventType = RESPONSE) Then
            '
            Select Case bRequestType
                Case ENUM_REQUEST_TYPE.REFERENCE_DATA: getServerData_reference
                Case ENUM_REQUEST_TYPE.HISTORICAL_DATA: getServerData_historical
                Case ENUM_REQUEST_TYPE.BULK_REFERENCE_DATA: getServerData_bulkReference
            End Select
            '
            If (bEvent.EventType = RESPONSE) Then bExit = True
        End If
    Loop
End Function
'
Private Function getServerData_reference()
    '
    Set bIterator = bEvent.CreateMessageIterator
    Do While (bIterator.Next)
        Set bIteratorData = bIterator.Message
        Set bSecurities = bIteratorData.GetElement("securityData")
        Dim offsetNumber As Long, i As Long, j As Long
        nSecurities = bSecurities.Count
        '
        For i = 0 To (nSecurities - 1)
            Set bSecurity = bSecurities.GetValue(i)
            Set bSecurityName = bSecurity.GetElement("security")
            Set bSecurityField = bSecurity.GetElement("fieldData")
            Set bSequenceNumber = bSecurity.GetElement("sequenceNumber")
            offsetNumber = CInt(bSequenceNumber.Value)
            '
            For j = 0 To UBound(bInputFieldArray)
                If (bSecurityField.HasElement(bInputFieldArray(j))) Then
                    Set bFieldValue = bSecurityField.GetElement(bInputFieldArray(j))
                    '
                    If (bFieldValue.DataType = BLPAPI_INT32) Then
                        bOutputArray(offsetNumber, j) = VBA.CLng(bFieldValue.Value)
                    Else
                        bOutputArray(offsetNumber, j) = bFieldValue.Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    Loop
End Function
'
Private Function getServerData_bulkReference()
    '
    Set bIterator = bEvent.CreateMessageIterator
    nSecurity = nSecurity + 1
    '
    Do While (bIterator.Next)
        Set bIteratorData = bIterator.Message
        Set bSecurities = bIteratorData.GetElement("securityData")
        Dim offsetNumber As Long, i As Long, j As Long
        Dim nSecurities As Long: nSecurities = bSecurities.Count
        '
        Set bSecurity = bSecurities.GetValue(0)
        Set bSecurityField = bSecurity.GetElement("fieldData")
        '
        If (bSecurityField.HasElement(bInputFieldArray(0))) Then
            Set bFieldValue = bSecurityField.GetElement(bInputFieldArray(0))
            '
            If ((bFieldValue.NumValues - 1) > UBound(bOutputArray, 2)) Then _
                ReDim Preserve bOutputArray(0 To UBound(bOutputArray, 1), 0 To bFieldValue.NumValues - 1)
            '
            For i = 0 To bFieldValue.NumValues - 1
                Set bDataPoint = bFieldValue.GetValue(i)
                bOutputArray(nSecurity - 1, i) = bDataPoint.GetElement(0).Value
            Next i
        End If
    Loop
End Function
'
Private Function getServerData_historical()
    '
    Set bIterator = bEvent.CreateMessageIterator
    Do While (bIterator.Next)
        Set bIteratorData = bIterator.Message
        Set bSecurities = bIteratorData.GetElement("securityData")
        Dim nSecurities As Long: nSecurities = bSecurityArray.Count
        Set bSecurityField = bSecurities.GetElement("fieldData")
        Dim nItems As Long, offsetNumber As Long, nFields As Long, i As Long, j As Long
        nItems = bSecurityField.NumValues
        If (nItems = 0) Then Exit Function
        If ((nItems > UBound(bOutputArray, 2))) Then _
            ReDim Preserve bOutputArray(0 To nSecurities - 1, 0 To nItems - 1)
        '
        Set bSequenceNumber = bSecurities.GetElement("sequenceNumber")
        offsetNumber = CInt(bSequenceNumber.Value)
        '
        If (bSecurityField.Count > 0) Then
            For i = 0 To (nItems - 1)
                '
                If (bSecurityField.Count > i) Then
                    Set bFields = bSecurityField.GetValue(i)
                    If (bFields.HasElement(bFieldArray(0))) Then
                        '
                        Dim d(0 To 1) As Variant
                        d(0) = bFields.GetElement(0).GetValue(0)
                        d(1) = bFields.GetElement(1).GetValue(0)
                        bOutputArray(offsetNumber, i) = d
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Loop
End Function
'
Private Function releaseObjects()
    '
    Set bFieldValue = Nothing
    Set bSequenceNumber = Nothing
    Set bSecurityField = Nothing
    Set bSecurityName = Nothing
    Set bSecurity = Nothing
    Set bSecurities = Nothing
    Set bIteratorData = Nothing
    Set bIterator = Nothing
    Set bEvent = Nothing
    Set bFieldArray = Nothing
    Set bSecurityArray = Nothing
    Set bRequest = Nothing
    Set bService = Nothing
    bSession.Stop
    Set bSession = Nothing
End Function
'
Private Function convertDateToBloombergString(ByVal d As Date) As String
    '
    ' convert date data type into string format YYYYMMDD
    Dim dayString As String: dayString = VBA.CStr(VBA.Day(d)): If (VBA.Day(d) < 10) Then dayString = "0" + dayString
    Dim MonthString As String: MonthString = VBA.CStr(VBA.Month(d)): If (VBA.Month(d) < 10) Then MonthString = "0" + MonthString
    Dim yearString As String: yearString = VBA.Year(d)
    convertDateToBloombergString = yearString + MonthString + dayString
End Function
'
Private Function getMax(ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long) As Long
    '
    getMax = a: If (b > a) Then getMax = b
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your description is very detailed - and what exactly is your question? Please be very specific on what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity -- how do I format by BLPSubscribe request to return the Security Description from Bloomberg successfully?

Comment: I added your question to the text above.

Comment: Thanks for the help Matt :)

Comment: `SECURITY_DES` is not a real time field - you need to run a reference data request. There are examples in the docs.

Comment: Thanks assylias -- you are of course correct and my working model did submit a reference data request.  I'm not sure where the "docs" are (I tried <WAPI> <GO> but found the page quite disorganized) but I would love to have a nice chunk of reference material to read up on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd format it by placing "Cusip" after the CUSIP number.
So BloombergReturnData = BloombergModule.BLPSubscribe("xxxxxxx Cusip", BloombergFields) would return the required fields.
I tested using your Cusip list and it does populate the variant with the correct field data.

Please note that the ActiveX control you're using is no longer supported by Bloomberg.  There is a COM Data Control using the "v3" interface.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the reference I was using from "Bloomberg Data Type Library" to "Bloomberg API COM 3.5 Type Library".

I then referenced a pre-written Bloomberg Class Module made to optimize Bloomberg calls which I found at this URL (thanks Mikael Katajamäki): http://mikejuniperhill.blogspot.com/2013/06/bloomberg-v3com-api-wrapper-update-for.html

I was getting an empty variant back using the refactored code until I reformatted my security name as "/cusip/xxxxxxxxx".  Will post new code in an edit to the original question.